# Nested dropdowns with vue2

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to do nested dropdowns using vue2 and I am using bootstrap. And here how far I went:

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown flex-plan-dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-expanded="false" @click="toggleDropdown">
          Dropdown
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" :class="{ show: isDropdownOpen }">
          <li class="dropdown-item"><button class="dropdown-item">Cluster</button></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item">
              <button class="dropdown-item " @click="toggleSubmenu">Measure <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" :class="{ show: isSubmenuOpen }">
                  <li><button class="dropdown-item d-flex">Sub1</button></li>
                  <li><button class="dropdown-item d-flex">Sub2</button></li>
                  <li><button class="dropdown-item d-flex">Sub3</button></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item">
              <button class="dropdown-item " @click="toggleSubmenu2">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" :class="{ show: isSubmenuOpen2 }">
                <li><button class="dropdown-item d-flex">Sub1</button></li>
                <li><button class="dropdown-item d-flex">Sub2</button></li>
                <li><button class="dropdown-item d-flex">Sub3</button></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return {
          isDropdownOpen: false,
          isSubmenuOpen2: false,
          isSubmenuOpen: false,
      };
  },
  methods: {
      toggleDropdown() {
          this.isDropdownOpen = !this.isDropdownOpen;
      },
      toggleSubmenu2(e) {
          this.isSubmenuOpen2 = !this.isSubmenuOpen2;
          e.stopPropagation();
      },
      toggleSubmenu(e) {
          this.isSubmenuOpen = !this.isSubmenuOpen;
          e.stopPropagation();
      },
  },
};
</script>
```

So I can open dropdowns and close them but they are not synchronized. When I open one of them and click the other one, the first one I opened is not close. What can be the effiient solution for it?

Comment: These are just buttons and list elements.  You should mention or tag what UI library and version you're using that is actually making these dropdowns.  It's likely you want help from someone familiar with the specific library, but right now it's not known.